# Converting an array of strings containing range of integer values into an array of floats

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, spyder, sklearn-pandas

[Click here to see an image that contains a screenshot sample of the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTuaI.png) 
I have a CSV file with a column for temperature range with values like "20-25" stored as string. I need to convert this to 22.5 as a float. 
**Need this to be done for the entire column of such values, not a single value**.I want to know how this can be done in Python as i am very new to it.

**Notice in the sample data image that there are NaN values as well in the records**

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: You can read every line, split it at the "-" using `tmp = line.split("-")` then convert the 2 values to string and get the average (`.5*( float(tmp[0])+float(tmp[1]) )`).

Comment: For easily reading CSV files in Python: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: The sample data in the column would be something similar to

**Temperatures**
        "20-25"
        "18-22"
        "21-24"
        "24-28"
and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in the reactions split the array using "-" as argument.
Second, create a float array of it. Finally, take the average using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

temp_input =  ["20-25", "36-40", "10-11", "23-24"]

# split and convert to float
# [t.split("-") for t in temp_input] is an inline iterator
tmp = np.array([t.split("-") for t in temp_input], dtype=np.float32)

# average the tmp array
temp_output = np.average(tmp, axis=1)
```

And here's a oneliner:

```
temp_output = [np.average(np.array(t.split('-'), dtype=np.float32)) for t in temp_input]
```